# creating tree based upon given values and parent id's

Tags: java, data-structures, recursion

```
    values 1           parent values

     3                    0
     4                    0
     5                    3
     6                    3 
     7                    5 
     8                    5
```

In above values and parents are datas using this if parent value zero than it is root. For instance above

```
                      3
                     /  \
                    5    6
                   /\
                  7   8
```

Consider this scenario i get values1 and parent values dynamically and then how it is convert to above tree like structure. i dont how much values comes in values1 and parent ie large values also come

Comment: What have you done so far, and what are your ideas? Have you written any code?

Comment: No Mr.Aasmund i did not write any code.just i want to apply,based on above child and parent relation i want to create a tree.

Comment: Try to solve it first, post your code if you have any problems.

Comment: I think that the whole purpose of this website is to get ideas and suggestions when you are stuck, not when you did not even attempt to solve it. I would rather attempt to solve it, share my code in stackoverflow and then benefit from the tips and the suggestions from the fellow users.

Comment: Dear Marcelo i didn't have an idea to start it,that's why i ask this question i am a beginner please give some ideas to solve it.

Comment: no not like that Mr.Wesam if i know i don't ask to this forum please first understand that

Comment: k thank u for all right or wrong after i try i come again ...

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints to how this problem can be solved:

- You should create a class to represent tree nodes. That class should have an `int` field that contains the value in the node, and a `List<Node>` that can contain the children of the node.
- You need a list where you can store all nodes you have created so far.
- For each row, go through the node list and see of you already have created the node that contains the value and the node that contains the parent value. If not, create the nodes. Then, add the child node to the parent node's list of children.